# Powershell: Using Invoke-WebRequest, How To Use Variable Within JSON?

Tags: json, powershell

Using Powershell, I'm trying to PUT data into an API, but I'm having trouble using a variable within the JSON:

This code below does not generate an error from the API, but it PUTS the `singer` as, literally, "$var_currentsinger" and doesn't use the intended variable

```
$currentsinger = "Michael Jackson"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://stackoverflow.com -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body '{
  "album": {
    "name": "Moonlight Sonata",
    "custom_fields": [{
      "singer": "$currentsinger",
      "songwriter": "Etta James"
    }]
  }
}'
```

This version below does not work, I assume because there are no quotes around the `singer` name. The API returns a value that the data is invalid

```
$currentsinger = "Michael Jackson"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://stackoverflow.com -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body '{
  "album": {
    "name": "Moonlight Sonata",
    "custom_fields": [{
      "singer": $currentsinger,
      "songwriter": "Etta James"
    }]
  }
}'
```

The only thing I have tried is double quotes and triple quotes around the variable, but I either get  the $currentsinger variable within the JSON and have it submit the variable value and not the variable name.

Comment: json often (always?) only allows double-quotes. You can escape each internal double-quote with backtick, or join single-quoted strings together

Comment: try with double quoted here-string `-Body @" .... "@`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Can you make that an answer? I don't know if I understand how to implement what you're saying to try.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I got it done based on your advice. Please make it an answer and I'll accept it. I ended up doing backtickdoublequote for each internal double quote (too hard to put as inline comment code, so I'll paste my final code once you post as an answer)

Comment: Instead of generating the json text yourself, consider creating a nested hashtable and using ```ConvertTo-Json``` as it will handle a whole multitude of edge-case for you - for example, what if ```$currentsinger = “James `”Godfather of Soul`” Brown”``` - you’d end up with invalid json by just interpolating the variable value into a json string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires double-quotes, so one example way to handle is by escaping the quotes or with a double-quoted here-string:

```
# here-string
$json = @"
  "singer": $currentsinger,
  "songwriter": "Etta James"
"@

# escaped
$json = "
  `"singer`": $currentsinger,
  `"songwriter`": `"Etta James`"
"
```